# Transcribe add-on: How to output content depending on the language selected

Tags: transcribe

I am running Transcribe add-on to manage a multi language website and I am trying the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
{if '{transcribe:language_abbreviation}' == 'en'}
          {exp:structure:nav start_from="/about" include_ul="no"}
{/if}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE** It actually works but my template for some reason wasn't updating EE. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works but my template for some reason wasn't updating EE. Sorry about this.